# How to retrieve array from database

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc, arraylist

I have created json in javascript and I am putting this json in one array. I have stored the array in a database field named "exp_values" like :

```
[{"concentration":"5","answers":10},{"concentration":"5","answers":20},{"concentration":"5","answers":78}]
```

I want to retrieve from the database. I am using spring and I created pojo(bean) class like

```
    public class ExperimentParameterBean {

      private String username;
      private String[] exp_values;  

      public String getUsername() {
        return username;
      }
      public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
      }
      public String[] getExp_values() {
        return exp_values;
      }
      public void setExp_values(String[] arrayData) {
        this.exp_values = arrayData;
      } 
}
```

I used hibernate for retrieving values from the database. I want this array as it is 
in java. How can I do this? I have knowledge of spring and hibernate. I want to only get this array from the database in the JSONObject fromat.

Comment: You'll have to store the value as a string in database, and perform the conversion to JSON while retrieving the value.

Comment: Do you want help in **1** filling the array from DB **or** **2** creating the JSON from array?

Comment: actually my quetion is I am storing JSON array as I mension above and I want to retrive fron database and save into the JSON object in java

Comment: actually i am storing as a string but while retrieving from database how to convert that string to JSON

Comment: my problem solved ......i am storing json as text datatype in mysql..thanks to all !!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem solved. i am storing json as text datatype in mysql